# Using jQuery to Fill Text Fields and Select Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, uiwebview

I'd like to have a user input stored in a variable, which will then go into a webpage such as [this one](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1-Nln9a9A3opd-N7ZFLe3WiuFMnzYLwsSZsR98GjFL84/viewform)

To clarify, I would like to have the app put data stored in a variable into an input field on a website (like the input field in that example form), and choose bubbles to fill in (like the multiple choice question in the example form).

I was told that I can use [jQuery Selectors](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) to do something like in this blog post (tinyurl.com/mk47wda), and I think I partially understand this, but not fully.

So, for example, if, in this page (which is open in a UIWebView), if I wanted to:

- put the string from variable x in the "Example String Question" field
- check "Option 2" in the "Example Multiple Choice Question" field
- put the string from variable y in the "Example String Question 2"
  field

What code would I type?

---

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If jquery then use

```
$('#question1').val(x);
$('#option2').attr('checked',true);
$('#question2').val(y);
```